# Browsers became extremely slow with jupyter lab

Tags: performance, ubuntu, firefox, chromium, jupyter-lab

I was working in jupyter lab on a server through a FF 72 for 3 days and it was normal. But after I cleared all cell outputs it instantly became very very slow.

Mouse reaction, keyboard reaction times reach 2-3 seconds. Scrolling is more or less okay, but clicking, typing are way too slow for normal work.

The notebook itself is not big (maybe 50 cells, cells are also not big), only python text, no graphs.

I've found this [jupyterlab issue 1639](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1639)  but it doesn't suggest any solution. Tried Chromium - even worse.

Any known solutions? Workarounds?

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you find anything? If yes, please post the solution.

Comment: I didn't find solution. After a day or two it became normal again.  I had that issue on both remote server and on the local computer, so most probably it's a browser issue, not conda/jupyter-lab's. Probably it's something with javascripts.

Try restarting your computer and browser.

Comment: @Hadij Any update? Having same issue but restarting computer and kernel doesnt seem to help

Comment: @AxW I just switched to visual studio code. I am happier now!

Answer (score 4):

Not saying this is the answer for everyone but I too was having the same problem of a laggy jupyterlab notebook where mine was specific to keyboard/typing lag. It was driving me nuts.

My setup is a 2 core proc and 4GB RAM (MacOS), Safari - all running the current OS.

My notebook is at 2640 lines.

I started trying different settings in Jupyterlab (e.g., stopped the kernel, turned off autosave..). Nothing worked.

Then I turned my eye toward web browsers and that was my culprit. It turns out Opera, for me, is the snappiest when working with Jupyterlab in my setup. Might want to give it a try.

I have zero lag now.